# Is there any IIS equivalent to Tomcat?

Tags: asp.net, iis, cassini

I want to test ASP.NET applications to get the feel for the MVC extension and compare that to what I can do today with Grails or Rails.
The trouble is that being in a corporate environment, I can't install IIS on my workstation, neither on my DEV server. And - you guessed it - Visual Studio is not to be considered at that moment (I guess for my investigations I'll stick with [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) and the .NET SDK for the time being).

On the Java side, I could unzip some Tomcat distribution in any folder and hit go.
Is there any equivalent in the IIS world, like a lightweight ASP.NET host?

Thanks,
Rollo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UltiDev Cassini Web Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltiDev_Cassini_Web_Server)

Comment: You will have problems installing the VS package if you're behind a firewall blocking the MSI downloads (the VS package installation will actually download the cassini web server and web server explorer).
You can download them manually. See here: http://ultidev.com/Forums/default.aspx?g=posts&t=239

Answer (score 1):

cassini runs locally. I'll get a link..

Edit: Here's the link to the [Cassini](http://www.asp.net/Downloads/archived/cassini/) Web Server

Answer (score 0):

UltiDev recently started shipping test builds of the Cassini replacement - [UltiDev Web Server Pro](http://ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postsm2726_Welcome-to-UltiDev-Web-Server-Pro.aspx). It requires elevated/admin privileges to be installed, but it can be downloaded for free. It's quite advanced, it's closer to IIS than Cassini. See [screenshots](http://ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postst659_UWS-Screenshots.aspx).